chktex: WARNING -- Unable to open the TeX file `#1'
I have a quite complicated tex file test when running chktex test,
the message below occurs
ChkTeX v1.7.8 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
chktex: WARNING -- Compilation of regular expression \[(?![^\]\[{}]*{(?![^\]\[{}]*}))[^\]]*\[ failed with error Invalid preceding regular expression.

chktex: WARNING -- Unable to open the TeX file `#1'.
No errors printed; No warnings printed; One user suppressed warning; 66 line suppressed warnings.

The first warning is not subject to this question, because it is asked somewhere else.
I focus on the second one.
Maybe someone can tell me without me to strip down the tex file.
What I consider strange is, that no line number is given.
This is quite atypical for chktex.
Or is it an internal warning, i.e. no warning on form of the tex file??

For chktex the extension .tex is irrelevant for sure.
From the hint of IvarAndrus, I found the line of code causing the warning,
so chktex read a considerable amount of the tex file

You get that message from passing #1 as the file name, see this terminal session:
$ chktex "#1"
ChkTeX v1.7.8 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
chktex: WARNING -- Unable to open the TeX file `#1'.

You get no line number as it is just telling you there is no input file of that name.
presumably you are calling chktex via some script where #1 is intended to be filled in by a filename, but it is somehow incorrectly quoted.

This is an explanation for getting no line number.
In fact I get the warning also when invoking manually chktex test.
Rest see answer to IvanAndrus.

Hard to say without looking at your file, but perhaps you have a custom macro defined in your header that uses \include?
\newcommand{\myinclude}[1]{\include{#1}}

Sadly, ChkTeX isn't really smart enough to parse macros like this and will blindly try to include the file.  Moving the LaTeX macro definition to a personal or project package (sty file) can work around the problem.
Another way to work around the problem is to use \csname, like
\newcommand{\myinclude}[1]{\csname include\endcsname{#1}}

This is ugly, and I wouldn't normally recommend it, but since it seems the macro in question exists to work around ChkTeX anyway, maybe it's worth it.

you are right. I found that line of code. It is
\newcommand{\inputNoChk}[1]{\input{#1}} % chktex 27.
Maybe also interesting, without chktex 17 I get
Warning 27 in header.tex line 229: Could not execute LaTeX command.
\newcommand{\inputNoChk}[1]{\input{#1}}  


I don't understand your explanation how to fix the problem.

The intention for my redefinition is, to prevent chktex from entering into the input file.
This is by
WipeArg {
 ...
  \inputNoChk:{}
}


Still an open question is why I did not get the line number, 229 and also needed the input file header.tex?

I reread the explanation for warning 27 and read there,
'Could not execute LaTeX command.'. So chktex does detect a problem.
Wouldnt it be a good idea to just drop the definition if endowed with '% chktex 27'?

I added another way to work around the issue that might be simpler.  I might also be able to have warning 27 suppress the error, but the way the code is structured today it's not trivial and I'm not sure it's the right thing.

let me know the details.. .. well or when you are finished.
